# How to type hint

Tags: clojure

How would I type hint this to get rid of the remaining reflection calls?

```
(def B 
     (amap ^"[[D" A i ^"[[D" B 
          (amap ^doubles (aget A (int i)) j ^doubles row 
             (* 2 (aget row (int j))))))
```

There's two reflection calls left, but I don't know how to get rid of them.

Comment: I should probably say what I think the code is doing in case I messed it up. I'm just trying to multiply all the elements in a 2d java array by 2 using amap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show your complete code or the reflection warnings, but if they are what I think they are, you'll need to:

1. hint A: `(def ^"[[D" A ...)` wherever you define it
2. cast the return value of the innermost expression to double: `(double (* 2 ...))`

The process to come up with these fixes is to perform macroexpand on the macro, run that version, see what expressions are causing the reflection warnings, fix them, and hope that you can retrofit the hints into the original macro, which in this case is possible. I still recommend the more straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO this is easier to do without the amap macro:

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
(def ^"[[D" A (into-array [(double-array [0 1 2]) (double-array [2 3 4])]))

(def ^"[[D" B (into-array (map aclone A))) ; aclone is shallow
(dotimes [i (alength B)]
  (let [^doubles row (aget B i)]
    (dotimes [j (alength row)]
      (aset row j (double (* 2 (aget row j)))))))

(doseq [row B]
  (prn (vec row)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already got a solution along those lines. I'm actually interested in comparing the imperative style code you wrote to the more functional style using amap.

Comment: Do note that amap is a macro that expands to something very much like the imperative solution.

Answer (score 0):

This page (in the end) provides good info about type hinting: http://clojure.org/java_interop. It recommends using e.g. (let [n (int)]) instead of ^Integer etc, which also makes the code much more readable. Note that a lot of the material on the internet seems to be for older versions of Clojure and you need less type hints in 1.2.