# How do I call a Clojure function that takes a two-dimensional array of Strings from Java?

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop

Basically question says it all.

When I declare a function signature in gen-class, what type do I put for a 2D array of strings?

```
[myFunc [XXXX] ReturnType]
```

what do I put for XXXX?

Update : following @Mark Topolnik's suggestion, I'm trying

```
#^{:static true} [myFunc [ ^"[[Ljava.lang.String;" ] clojure.lang.IFn]
```

in my declaration, and I'm getting back a

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unmatched delimiter: ]
```

runtime exception when I try to compile it.

Update 2 : Fixed by removing the ^ from the above line. (This is in the context of declaring function signatures in a gen-class so that ^ is presumably unnecessary.)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779876/how-to-type-hint. So I guess `^"[[Ljava.lang.String" strings` would be the only (ugly) way.

Comment: Isn't that a single dimension of array?

Comment: The number of initial open-brackets specifies the depth of the array.

Comment: Ah ... that's something I didn't pick up on. I always thought it was the L that meant List or something that made it an array. What does the L mean then?

Comment: Who knows what `L` stands for as a mnemonic, but it means "reference type" and requires the fully-qualified name of the type to follow, ending with `;` (I forgot that one in my comment).

Comment: Actually, when I try it I'm getting an unmatched delimiter exception (updated the question)

Comment: But you didn't name your variable. The type hint metadata must refer to *something*.

Comment: Ah ... I fixed it. Didn't need the ^ in this context (it's a function declaration in a class-gen). Sorry. I'm still a bit hazy on the sigils in Clojure.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, it looks like you answered the question in the comments.  Shouldn't you record it as an official answer, so that interstar can accept it?

Comment: Agree with Mars @MarkoTopolnik . Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multidimensional array types have no direct support in Clojure, but you can always fall back to using a String with the binary type name. In your case, this would look like the following:

```
[myFunc ["[[Ljava.lang.String;"] ReturnType]
```